# How to use .save() in seed data for mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With this code I'm unsure whether to use `examBoard.save()` after pushing each 'question' into the 'examBoard' or just after pushing the last 'question' into 'examBoard' like I have in the code I've put.

```js
 examBoard.create({
   name: "AQA",
   modules: [{
     name: "c1",
     topics: ["c1a", "c1b", "c1c"]
   }, {
     name: "c2",
     topics: ["c2a", "c2b", "c2c"]
   }, {
     name: "c3",
     topics: ["c3a", "c3b", "c3c"]
   }],
   function(err, examBoard) {
     if (err) {
       console.log("Failed to make new exam board\n" + err);
     } else {
       //=================================
       //adding question to AQA exam board
       //=================================
       question.create({
         text: "question 1a",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[0].topics[0].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 1b",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[0].topics[1].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 1c",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[0].topics[2].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 2a",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[1].topics[0].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 2b",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[1].topics[1].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 2c",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[1].topics[2].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 3a",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[2].topics[0].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 3b",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[2].topics[1].push(question);
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       question.create({
         text: "question 3c",
         parts: [
           ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
           ["2a", "2b", "2c"],
           ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
         ]
       }, function(err, question) {
         if (err) {
           console.log("Failed to make new question\n" + err);
         } else {
           examBoard.modules[2].topics[2].push(question);
           examBoard.save();
           console.log("New question made\n" + question);
         }
       });
       console.log("New exam board made\n" + examBoard);

     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: Your post seems to be a request for Code Review - the best place for the kind of questions is [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Okay thanks for saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The way you're doing it, is fine.**

Because if any question fails and any error occurs in between, your complete transaction will fail and you will not have half of questions saved in the DB.

In other case (saving after every question) may end up half questions saved and rest not in case of an error.
And when you'll respond to the client that the transaction has failed, client will post the data again and it will create duplicate question/examBoard (those who got saved before the error).

Comment: I don't think it's fine, there are just too many callbacks in the code with a potential of callback hell. Would suggest using promises or the async library with the above logic.

Comment: I was referring to the logic of `document save`. Not the code actually.